# Count errors being thrown inside a map() call, js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am mapping over an array of integers to make a series of API calls. I want to count the number of times an exception is being thrown, if any.

This is what I am currently working with:

```
                let errorCount = 0;
                let transformedArr = [];
                try {
                    transformedArr = targets.map(element =>
                        Observable.fromPromise(SendRequest(ApiController.API_NAME, {
                            urlParams: { id: element.id }
                        }))
                    );
                } catch (err) {
                    errorCount += 1;
                }
```

However, the errorCount is never updated from its initial value of 0. Based on the error count, I will be rendering different components. I know that map() doesn't break on exception, so I wanted to find out how many times the call failed.

Comment: I have submited a very long answer. If you don't want to read it all check out the last snippet...

Comment: Basically, when an error is thrown in the function provided to map(), the map() function will not assign anything to `transformedArr`. So you get no results. Also the first error will prevent any further processing of elements as it immediately transfers control to the catch block. So you can never increment errorCount by more 1.

Comment: The fact that you are not getting errorCount to increment beyond 0 could be because you are not getting any errors in the function you provide to map.

Comment: Are you getting any elements passed into `transformedArr`?

Answer (score -1):

In this code snippet the for loop proceeds and pushes results to the result array until there is an error. Then it jumps out of the try block into the catch block. errorCount will never be incremented more than once.

```js
let errorCount = 0;

let results = [];

try {
  for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    if(i === 7){
      throw 'err';
    } else {
      results.push(i);
    }
  }
} catch(err) {
  errorCount += 1;
}

console.log('errorCount', errorCount);
console.log('results', results);
```

If instead of the *for loop* you use map to iterate through an array and there is a single element anywhere in the starting array which causes an error to be thrown, then the map function will fail completely. So you will increment the errorCount variable once even if many elements in the starting array did not throw an error before the element that did throw the error. Worse still, nothing gets assigned to your result array (transformedArr):

```js
let errorCount = 0;
let transformedArr = [];

let targets = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

try {
  transformedArr = targets.map(element => {
    if(element === 'c'){
      throw 'err';
    }
    return element.toUpperCase();
  });
} catch(err) {
  errorCount += 1;
}

console.log('errorCount', errorCount);
console.log('transformedArr', transformedArr);
```

If you comment out the `throw 'err';` line all the elements in the targets array end up in the transformedArr:

```js
let errorCount = 0;
let transformedArr = [];

let targets = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

try {
  transformedArr = targets.map(element => {
    if(element === 'c'){
      // throw 'err';
    }
    return element.toUpperCase();
  });
} catch(err) {
  errorCount += 1;
}

console.log('errorCount', errorCount);
console.log('transformedArr', transformedArr);
```

The solution appears to be to put the try catch block inside the function supplied to map:

```js
let errorCount = 0;
let transformedArr = [];

let targets = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

  transformedArr = targets.map(element => {
    try {
      if(element === 'c'){
        throw 'err';
      }
      return element.toUpperCase();
    } catch(err) {
      errorCount += 1;
    }
  });

console.log('errorCount', errorCount);
console.log('transformedArr', transformedArr);
```

Here is an example with 2 errors. You can see now errorCount increments beyond 1 and the transformedArr is populated with elements beyond the first error.

```js
let errorCount = 0;
let transformedArr = [];

let targets = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

  transformedArr = targets.map(element => {
    try {
      if(element === 'b' || element === 'd'){
        throw 'err';
      }
      return element.toUpperCase();
    } catch(err) {
      errorCount += 1;
    }
  });

console.log('errorCount', errorCount);
console.log('transformedArr', transformedArr);
```